# Binary string to binary number

Tags: python, binary

I need to convert binary string e.g. 1011 to binary number in python. I used this code but it gives me one more 0 to end

```
bin(int(''.join(map(str, x)), 2) << 1)
```

x is string which I want to convert. Could someone help me how to do it?

Comment: If `x` is already a string, then `''.join(map(str, x))` is completely unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want? am I missing something?

```
>>> binary_string = '1011'
>>> binary_integer = int(binary_string, 2)
>>> binary_integer
11
>>> binary_literal = bin(binary_integer)
>>> binary_literal
'0b1011'
```

If this is not what you want, can you elaborate? what is the input, and what is the desired output? I hope i could help.

Comment: Hey Ali, I have a similar problem, and the problem with your solution is that it is still a string. I suppose the initial problem was (like mine), how to transform that binary string to a binary integer. Any ideas?